# Excel formula to alter cell's background color but keep its current value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have two very large Excel spreadsheets. One is the original sheet, and the other is the output of my application I am writing, which seems to be changing cell values. I'd like to see if there is a pattern to how it is changing them.

I have copied the output spreadsheet into the original a few columns to the right of the original data. What I would like to do is create a formula to change the cell background color if the value in the output data is not the same as the input data.

I have found [this guide online](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/18/change-background-color-excel-based-on-cell-value/) which shows a way to apply a rule to edit, from what I can tell, all cells' background values in some manner. But in the Excel dialogue "Create new rule" you can make one based on a formula, though this formula applies to all cells.

What I need is a formula where I can compare the current cell value to another cell value, and change the background color accordingly. I can then apply it to each column in the output data, drag down, and I should be able to see the altercations my software has made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tag with your Excel version or provide any sample data, so let's say you are using Excel 2007 or greater, and your worksheet looks like this:

[image]

To compare the cells in column `D` to the corresponding cells in column `A`, do the following:

1. Select cells `D2:D7` by clicking on cell `D2` and then dragging down to cell `D7`, so that cell `D2` is the Active Cell (as seen in the above screenshot)
2. On the Ribbon, click `Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule...`
3. In the **Select a Rule Type** section of the **New Formatting Rule** dialog, click **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
4. In the **Format values where this formula is true** textbox, enter the following formula: `=D2<>A2`
5. Click the **Format** button
6. In the **Format Cells** dialog, set your desired formatting (e.g. click the **Fill** tab, and select the Yellow color)
7. Click the **OK** button
8. In the **New Formatting Rule** dialog, click the **OK** button
9. Repeat the above steps, except select cells `E2:E7`, and use the formula `=E2<>B2`

Note:
Since the columns I am formatting are contiguous, I could have simply selected cells `D2:E7` instead of `D2:D7`, and then skipped step `9`. However, I am assuming that the columns you want to format are not necessarily contiguous.

Optional:
Since background-color formatting hides cell gridlines, one additional thing I like to do in the **Format Cells** dialog is to click the **Border** tab, select "White, Background 1, Darker 15%" in the **Color** dropdown, and then apply that color to the **Outline** borders. That way, your formatted cells will appear to retain their gridlines.

Result:

[image]

Comment: If you have a chance, I have asked a related question. http://superuser.com/questions/1144385/determine-if-multiple-cells-in-row-do-not-exist-in-another-selection