# Determine if multiple cells in row do not exist in another selection?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have two spreadsheets, an original and a modified, and I would like to determine if certain collections of cells in a given row in the modified do not exist in the original.

For example, if I have my original and modified data side by side in the same sheet as so

[image]

I would like to identify rows in the modified where `Col1` and `Col2` together do not exist in the original data ignoring the values in `Col3` as so

[image]

I think I should be able to do this with a custom formatting rule based upon a formula but I am not sure how I can apply a rule like this in a row order agnostic manner.

I have previously [asked a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1142546/excel-formula-to-alter-cells-background-color-but-keep-its-current-value) about doing something similar but this question assumed that all rows in the original, in a sense, match up with the modified. But I have found in the modified spreadsheet rows can be switched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your left-most "Col1" header is in cell `A1`, select cells `E2:F6` (with `E2` as the Active Cell), and use this formula for Conditional Formatting:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E2,$B:$B,$F2)=0
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I assume I can follow the pattern to include or ignore more columns as I like?

Comment: @KDecker yes, you can add columns to the COUNTIFS.

Comment: I was upset with myself for a second because I thought I had applied this wrong. Then I realized that I actually corrected modified the spreadsheet as I wanted. Thanks again MJH and Scott Craner!